# angularjs checking dirty status of elements inside particular div

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-validation

i have a form like this and i like to user angularjs for form validation

```
<form name="userrequest">
<div id="userdetails">
<input type="text" id="buyerName" />
</div>

<div id="buyerDetails">
<input type="text" id="buyerName" />
<input type="text" id="buyercity" />
</div>
</form
```

how can i check any input elements inside buyerDetails div is in dirty state?

Comment: you could  use `form` and then do check `form.$dirty`

Comment: Thanks pankajparker , i dont want to check elements inside userdetails div. form.$dirty will check elements inside userdetails right? i want to check only elements inside div buyerdetails.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `ng-model` on each `form` field with `name` attribute, that will enable the dirty checking on form elements. You could check any form field dirty or not by using its `name`

**Markup**

```
<form name="userrequest">
    <div id="userdetails">
        <input type="text" id="buyerName" name="userBuyerName" 
         ng-model="form.user.buyerName" />
    </div>
    Dirty
    <br/> form.user.buyerName {{userrequest.userBuyerName.$dirty}}

    <div id="buyerDetails">
        <input type="text" id="buyerName" name="buyerName" 
         ng-model="form.buyer.buyerName" />
        <input type="text" id="buyercity" name="buyerName" 
         ng-model="form.buyer.buyerName" />
    </div>
    Dirty
    <br/> form.buyer.buyerName {{userrequest.buyerName.$dirty}}
    <br/> form.buyer.buyercity {{userrequest.buyercity.$dirty}}

</form>


Is form is Dirty {{userrequest.$dirty}}
```